# Trying to make a counter that will have its output multiplied by some fixed value

Tags: python, pygears

I'm trying to make a counter that will have its output multiplied by some fixed value; the code is below:

```
from pygears.lib import qrange, mul
qrange(10) | mul(2)
```

The error I'm getting is this one:

```
TypeMatchError: [0], Queue[Uint[4], 1] cannot be matched to Number
       - when matching Tuple[Uint[2], Queue[Uint[4], 1]] to Tuple[{'a': Number, 'b': Number}]
       - when deducing type for argument "din"
       - when instantiating "mul"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what pygears is, but you're looking for:

> A counter that will have its output multiplied by some fixed value

So here you go:

```
# Choose your fixed value
fixed_value = 42

# Choose lower and upper bounds
left, right = 0, 5

# Multiply each index by fixed value
output_values = [i * fixed_value for i in range(left, right)]

print(output_values)
```

Output: `[0, 42, 84, 126, 168]`

Does that help?